# Passing data between middelware

Tags: php, middleware, psr-7, mezzio

I use zend-expressive and i would like to pass data from one middelware to another.
e.g. in config/routes.php I've

```
[
    'name' => 'v1.item.list',
    'path' => '/item',
    'allowed_methods' => ['GET'],
    'middleware' => [
        Api\V1\Action\ItemListAction::class,
        Application\Middleware\JsonRenderMiddleware::class
    ]
],
```

in Api\V1\Action\ItemListAction I'm preparin some data from databases and I like to pass $itemsList to another middelware

```
public function __invoke(ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, callable $next = null)
{
    $parameters = new ListParameters($request->getQueryParams());
    $itemsList = $this->commandBus->handle(new ItemListCommand($parameters));
    return $next($request, $response);
}
```

and in Application\Middleware\JsonRenderMiddleware I would like get $itemsList and return in json format:

```
public function __invoke(ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, callable $next = null)
{
    return new JsonResponse($itemsList);
}
```

How is the best way? Only commandBus or is other solution in this framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the attributes of the `$request`.

In `Api\V1\Action\ItemListAction` you could do

$request = $request->withAttribute('list', $itemsList);

and then retrieve it in `Application\Middleware\JsonRenderMiddleware` using

$itemsList = $request->getAttribute('list');

The only drawback of this solution is that you are creating a dependency between the two middlewares, because the second one will break if the `$request` does not have a `list` attribute

Comment: it's doesn't work :/ $response->getAttribute('list'); always returns null even when i try get it right after set it in this same middleware.

Comment: Maybe I can not properly understand the idea of middleware. I thought that I can use middleware like some service chain to process data in many ways to receive expected data. Like in this case i want to use different middleware to receive e.g. json or html response, but use this same middleware to retrieve data from DB.

Comment: there was a mistake, `getAttribute` needs to be called on `$request`, not on `$response`

Comment: of course I tried it on $request but still dosen't work. Even in this: `$newReqest = $request->withAttribute('data', $item);
        $data = $newReqest->getAttributes();
        return $next($newReqest, $response);` $data is null

Comment: ok, now it's works. I had file synchronisation issue with vagrant. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to go here.

Usually you would return a Zend\Diactoros\Response\JsonResponse in your action. Normally you want to extend that class and transform that list into something more useful. I wouldn't use the request to pass data like this.

However I see that you are using a command bus. I haven't worked with that yet, but you might want to have a look at https://github.com/prooph/proophessor-do. That's a nice example on how they use CQRS and Event Sourcing with expressive.